# can i get the same effect as in photoshop using font-family:Helvetica Neue Light

Tags: css

want to get the same effect as looks in this picture

http://www.screencast.com/users/netcane/folders/Jing/media/801aaeab-ad76-4b5d-ae2a-3ed4d463f2ae

using css font-family:Helvetica Neue Light is it possible or i have to use cufon ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of any copyright issues to doing this but here is a good read on how to embed fonts in webpages so you can use them in your css.

http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1306847,00.asp

Comment: Hi Randy Thanks...as i said i want to know i can use this style in css or not ?...regarding embeding i prefer cufón